# Как узнать по какой ссылке была вызвана контактная форма?

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка, вызывающая контактную форму:

```
<a href="javascript:mmodal('mmodal1')" onclick="yaCounter38542655.reachGoal('zvonok'); return true;">Обратный звонок</a>
```

При нажатии вызывается данная форма:

```
<div class="mmodal" id="mmodal1" style="top: 6%!important;">
    <div class="mclose"><a href="javascript:mclose();"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/exit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="mtitle">Заполните заявку и наши специалисты свяжутся с Вами в ближайшее время.</div>
    <div class="mbody">
        <form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/email.php" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя*" required></li>
                <li><input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон*" required></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Ваша компания"></li>
                <li><br>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcaFBoUAAAAAGloGyt2gPh2TCJeF2m1YAO5jwdZ"></div>
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" style="background: #fff;border: 1px solid #67b6fc;padding: 7px 40px 7px 40px;border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 40px;outline: none;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 600;" value="Оставить заявку" onclick="yaCounter39830690.reachGoal('zvonok'); return true;"></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <br>
        <span>или звоните</span> <br>
        <span style="font-size: 24px;">+7 (495) 532 52 62</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это скрипт:

```js
function mmodal(id) {
  win_w = jQuery(window).width();
  jQuery("#" + id).fadeIn("slow");
  jQuery("#mmodal").fadeIn("slow");
  jQuery("#mmodal").addClass("monmodalbg");
  jQuery(".monmodalbg").css('width', win_w);
}
```

На слайдере есть несколько таких ссылок, но нужно различать, на какую именно ссылку нажал пользователь, так как это разные услуги. Как можно вставить в тело письма текст, по которому было бы ясно с какого слайда была вызвана форма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит так использовать ссылки, кошерно юзать события:

```js
// Простейшее делегирование на раппер
document.querySelector("#wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  let target = e.target; // Вот тут мы получаем "автора" вызова
  if(target.nodeName === "SPAN")
    openModal.call(target, target.dataset.modalId);
});

/**
 * Вызов окна
 *
 * @param {String} id ID формы для вызова
 * @this {HTMLSpanElement} Элемент, который вызвал открытие окна, можно извлекать что угодно в письмо для маркировки
 */
function openModal(id){
  console.info(`Открываем окно "${id}" из слайда с текстом "${this.innerHTML}"!`);
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
   <span data-modal-id="modal1">Слайд 0</span>
   <span data-modal-id="modal1">Слайд 1</span>
   <span data-modal-id="modal2">Слайд 2</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что натолкнули в правильную сторону! Ваш код до конца не понял, но сделал немного по другому, используя тот же атрибут `data-modal-id` для определения ссылки. Я вставил в форму `input type="hidden"` и при клике на ссылку передавал значение в этот  input, а потом уже в PHP файле достал её и вставил в письмо.